# WebGL: Prevent color buffer from being cleared

Tags: html, webgl

Even if I remove

```
gl.clearColor(c[0],c[1],c[2],1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

the screen still gets cleared at the beginning of the
next draw cycle. Is there a way to prevent this.
I´d like to achive some kind of overpaint effect.

Comment: You're probably swapping buffers aka double buffering.

Comment: Ah, ok. The default behavior is to clear the drawing buffer. It has to disabled via the preserveDrawingBuffer attribute of the WebGLContextAttributes.

Answer (score 9):

When you create your WebGLRenderingContext you can tell it to preserve the drawing buffer.

```
gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
```

The default is `preserveDrawingBuffer: false` because it's faster in some cases.

Comment: it does not work with alpha:false. gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true , alpha:false });

Comment: "because it's faster in some cases." Could You exaplain why or when? Or paste some references.