# How to get a circle drawn at pointer location to stay on screen in threejs (mouse trail)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a mouse trail effect with threejs, basing it off of this example: https://medium.com/epicagency/behind-the-scenes-of-we-cargo-3999f5f559c (near the bottom of the page).

I've been trying this for a few days now, but I cannot get the circle which is drawn with an intensity derived from the cursor speed and fades over time, to stay on the screen as is shown in the example on the link provided. Everything is working fine in terms of drawing the circle based on cursor delta, but I cannot figure out how to actually keep the trail on screen. The circle only is drawn where the cursor is and all trails are erased on each animation frame. I've tried setting the canvas alpha to 0, I've tried using a FBO and using the mouse trail as an intermediate render target, I've tried hijacking the render function in the middle of the RAF hook (I'm using React Three Fiber), and I keep getting the same results. I'm not using the bidello helper class that the author is using, maybe there is some subtle thing that I'm missing in those helper classes that is the secret sauce... I don't know.

Plane.js

```
const Geometry = props => {

    const width = window.innerWidth
    const height = window.innerHeight

    const pointer = new THREE.Vector2()
    let speed = 0

    const uniforms = useMemo(
        () => ({
            u_mouse: { value: new THREE.Vector2() },
            u_speed: {
                value: 0,
            },
            u_time: { value: 0.0 },
            u_resolution: { value: { x: width, y: height } },
            u_ratio: {
                value: window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
            },
            u_texture: {
                value: new THREE.DataTexture(
                    new Float32Array(width * height * 4),
                    width,
                    height
                ),
            },
        }),
        []
    )

    var diff = new MouseSpeed()
    diff.init()

    const pointerMove = e => {
        pointer.set(e.x / window.innerWidth, 1 - e.y / window.innerHeight)

        pointer.x = (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1
        pointer.y = -(e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1

        uniforms.u_mouse.value.x = pointer.x
        uniforms.u_mouse.value.y = pointer.y
    }

    useFrame((state, delta) => {
        uniforms.u_time.value += delta

        uniforms.u_mouse.value.lerp(pointer, 0.2)
        uniforms.u_speed.value = speed
        // state.gl.render(state.scene, state.camera)
        // state.gl.setClearColor(0x000000, 0)

        const diffSpeed =
            Math.max(Math.abs(diff.speedX), Math.abs(diff.speedY)) * 0.05
        speed += diffSpeed
        speed *= 0.9
    })

    return (
        <>
            {/* {createPortal(<Trail />, scene)} */} // This was used when I was using an FBO
            <mesh onPointerMove={pointerMove}>
                <planeBufferGeometry args={[width, height, 1, 1]} />
                <shaderMaterial
                    uniforms={uniforms}
                    vertexShader={mainVert}
                    fragmentShader={mainFrag}
                    onUpdate={self => (self.needsUpdate = true)}
                />
            </mesh>
        </>
    )
}
```

shader.frag

```
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec3 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;
uniform float u_ratio;
uniform float u_speed;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution.xy;
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, v_uv + vec2(0.0, -0.002));
    
    vec2 center = (u_mouse.xy) / 2. + .5;
    uv.x *= u_ratio;
    center.x *= u_ratio;
    
    color.r += circle(uv, center, 0.0, .08) * u_speed;
    color.r = mix(color.r, 0.0, .009);
    color.r = clamp(color.r, 0.0, 1.0);
    
    color.g = color.r;
    
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Basically I'm just wondering what I have to do to get this working like the mouse trail animation in the example that I provided. As I said, everything is fine except for the actual trail itself to remain on the screen. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you track every circle that would need to be drawn and update them all each frame?

Comment: Well, no. I'm just going off the code in the example that I provided. I can't pinpoint what part of the code in the example is providing the mouse trail effect.

Comment: Oh, okay. Usually the view is cleared and redrawn every frame. Since this is so common, it's done automatically by default in WebGL. (In fact, hardware is now optimized around this.) To allow their effect, they turn off the automatic clearing and instead apply a blur/fade to the whole view. See [WebGL: Prevent color buffer from being cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606408/webgl-prevent-color-buffer-from-being-cleared)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this didn't solve my issue. I'm still getting just the circle on the cursor and no trail.

Comment: Do you have a runnable demo of your code?

Comment: Here's a codesandbox with a simplified recreation: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-babbage-q3978